# Construct views for data nested several levels deep

Tags: marionette

I'm trying to build an order system for a friend using django/tastypie on the server side and backbone/marionette on the client side. The server side poses no bigger problem but since I'm an inexperienced frontend developer I'm kinda stuck;

The simpler case went just fine, e.g. to list, add, edit and remove an Article (just a table in my database with sku, description and so on) using Composite- and ItemViews.The problem is when I'm trying to construct the views for an Order since it consists of several tables with relations on the server side.

Order
  LineItem
   Article
   StoreQuantity
      Store
   StoreQuantity
      Store

LineItem
   Article
   StoreQuantity
      Store
   StoreQuantity
      Store
  ...

So an Order consists of several LineItems. A LineItem consists of an Article and several StoreQuantity:s making it possible to model something like "Order Article A; 10 copies to Store X and 4 copies to Store Y, Article B; 4 copies to Store X and 1 copy to Store Y".

I guess my question is; how would I go about to construct my views for something like above?

Would something like below be the wrong way?

- Create an OrderCompositeView and pass it the OrderModel from my controller.
- When OrderModel is fetched from the server, let OrderCompositeView create a LineItemCompositeView.
- When LineItemCompositeView has fetched its' LineItemCollection from the server.. and so on recursively

Should I create a REST-url that returns the entire JSON for an Order and its relations instead of several smaller recursive calls, and then try to parse the JSON client side?

I've found several good resources on how to get going with Marionette but none on how to handle data nested several layers deep.

Thanks /Magnus

Edit:

Showing some code illustrating what I've been testing

(Views)

```
var LineItemDetailView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#lineitem-layout-template",
    tagName: "div",

    initialize: function() {
    }
});

var LineItemView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#lineitem-wrapper-template",
    childView: LineItemDetailView,
    childViewContainer: "div",

    initialize: function(coll, obj) {
        this.collection = new LineItemCollection({url: "api/v1/lineitem/?order__id=" + obj["order_id"]});
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                console.log("Successfully fetched lineitems");
            }

        });
    }
});

var OrderDetailView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#order-detail-template",
    childView: LineItemView,
    childViewContainer: "#lineitems",

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("sync", function(mod) {
           lineitemView = new LineItemView([],{order_id: mod.get("id")});
        });
    }
});
```

Something along those lines. OrderDetailView is created from my controller and passed the OrderModel. I from this I get OrderDetailView:s template to render and the LineItemCollection is fetched from server but nothing more happens.

Comment: Very interesting article by Derick Bailey - [Composite Views: Tree Structures, Tables, And More](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ran into this when creating a survey portion of an app the other day. It had a structure like this:
Survey:
   Question:
      Answer
      Answer
   Question:
      Answer
      Answer

So pretty similar to what you're doing. I used the backbone-relational gem - http://backbonerelational.org/ to relate the models together and it worked great. My API sends back all of the JSON in a single call. So surveys/1.json brings back all of the above pieces/their data. Then I parse/break them up with Backbone relational. Here's what they look like:

Survey:

```
class Entities.Survey extends App.Entities.Model
    urlRoot: "surveys"

    defaults: 
      status: "Draft"
      number_taken: 0
      survey_limit: 500

    relations: [
      type: Backbone.HasMany
      key: "questions"
      relatedModel: Entities.Question
      reverseRelation: 
        key: 'survey'
        includeInJSON: 'id'
    ]
```

Question:

```
class Entities.Question extends App.Entities.Model
    urlRoot: "questions"

    defaults:
      single_response: true
      terminate: false
      free_text: false

    relations: [
      type: Backbone.HasMany
      key: "answers"
      relatedModel: Entities.Answer
      reverseRelation: 
        key: 'question'
        includeInJSON: 'id'
    ]
```

Answer:

```
class Entities.Answer extends App.Entities.Model
    urlRoot: "answers"

    defaults:
      branching: false
      next_question_id: null
```

Then when you go to display them, in my survey display view I have a layout view that has a question region which uses a composite view of the survey questions like this:

```
class Show.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: (options) ->
      { survey, id } = options
      survey or= App.request "survey:entity", id

      App.execute "when:fetched", survey, =>
        @layout = @getLayoutView()

        @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
          @panelRegion survey
          @questionRegion survey
          @bannerRegion survey

        @show @layout

    questionRegion: (survey) ->
      App.request "show:survey:questions", survey, @layout.questionRegion
```

Then I come in and get the questions:

```
questionRegion: (survey) ->
      questions = survey.get('questions')
      questionView = @getQuestionView questions, survey
```

The childview of the Questions CompositeView is itself a CompositeView with a childview of answers.

So Survey has a Questions CompositeView of Questions, each of which is a CompositeView of Answers.

You should be able to follow a similar structure with your app. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere!

Edit: Adding View/Controllers.

So here's what I do, when the user navigates to a certain route - say localhost:3000/#surveys/1/edit it hits my surveysrouter (note some code like the list piece I stripped out):

```
@TheoremReach.module "SurveysApp", (SurveysApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class SurveysApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      "surveys"             : "list"
      "surveys/:id"         : "show"
      "surveys/:id/take": "take"

  API =
    show: (id, survey) ->
        new SurveysApp.Show.Controller
            id: id
            survey: survey

    take: (id, survey) ->
      new SurveysApp.Take.Controller 
        id: id 
        survey: survey

  App.vent.on "survey:clicked", (survey) ->
    App.navigate "surveys/" + survey.id
    API.show survey.id, survey

  App.vent.on "take:survey:button:clicked", (survey) ->
    App.navigate "surveys/" + survey.id + "/take"
    API.take survey.id, survey

  App.addInitializer ->
    new SurveysApp.Router
      controller: API
```

So I can get here when navigating or by triggering the "survey:clicked" event. This then creates my show controller:

```
@TheoremReach.module "SurveysApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: (options) ->
      { survey, id } = options
      survey or= App.request "survey:entity", id

      App.execute "when:fetched", survey, =>
        @layout = @getLayoutView()

        @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
          @panelRegion survey
          @questionRegion survey
          @bannerRegion survey

        @show @layout

    questionRegion: (survey) ->
      App.request "show:survey:questions", survey, @layout.questionRegion

    panelRegion: (survey) ->
      panelView = @getPanelView survey

      @listenTo panelView, "new:question:clicked", (args) ->
        question = App.request "new:question:entity"
        model = args.model
        model.get('questions').add(question)
        question.set(survey_id: model.get('id'))
        App.request "new:question:added"

      @show panelView, region: @layout.panelRegion

    bannerRegion: (survey) ->
      bannerView = @getBannerView survey

      @listenTo bannerView, "take:survey:button:clicked", (args) ->
        App.vent.trigger "take:survey:button:clicked", args.model

      @show bannerView, region: @layout.bannerRegion

    getLayoutView: ->
      new Show.Layout

    getBannerView: (survey) ->
      new Show.Banner
        model: survey

    getPanelView: (survey) ->
      new Show.Panel
        model: survey
```

This makes a new Questions Show Controller (same router case as above that handles `"show:survey:questions"` request and instigates a new controller so I'll skip that code).

```
@TheoremReach.module "QuestionsApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: (options) ->
      { survey } = options
      @layout = @getLayoutView()

      @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
        @questionRegion survey

      @show @layout

    questionRegion: (survey) ->
      questions = survey.get('questions')
      questionView = @getQuestionView questions, survey

      App.reqres.setHandler "new:question:added", ->
        questionView.render()

      @show questionView, region: @layout.questionRegion

    getLayoutView: ->
      new Show.Layout

    getQuestionView: (questions, survey) ->
      new Show.Questions
        collection: questions
        model: survey
```

Standard composite view for the questions:

```
class Show.Questions extends App.Views.CompositeView
    template: "questions/show/_questions"
    className: "questions"
    itemViewContainer: ".editor"
    itemView: Show.Question
```

Then each question is a composite view:

```
class Show.Question extends App.Views.CompositeView
    template: "questions/show/_question"
    id: "1000"
    className: "step"
    initialize: ->
      @collection = @model.get("answers")
      @model.set(question_number: @model.collection.indexOf(@model) + 1)
      if @model.get('free_text') and @model.get('answers').length < 1
        answer = App.request "new:answer:entity"
        answer.set(free_text: true, question: @model, title: @model.get('title'))
        @collection.reset(answer, {silent: true})
      @on "childview:answer:delete:clicked", (child, args) =>
        args.collection = @model.get('answers')
        @trigger "answer:delete:clicked", args

    itemView: Show.Answer 
    itemViewContainer: ".answer-container"
```

It gets its collection from the answers group from backbone relational. I would note though that this probably should just be a layout and in the initialize function I should send a request to the answers app to get a list of answers and add those to the answer region. I just haven't gotten around to that yet :).

Comment: Greatly appreciated!
I think your way of solving it sounds very nice and intuitive. I added a resource in my backend that returns a big JSON of an Order and its related data. I also updated my backbone models so now they're using backbone-relational. I can see that the entire tree of models/collections are generated from my JSON. Finally some progress! 

One thing I'm curious about is how you instantiate the views; Do you send your Survey-model to your Survey-view, and let your Survey-view extract the Questions-collection from the Survey-model and instantiate the Question-view and so on?

Comment: Sure - I added some code. Want to take a look and let me know if that all makes sense? Basically it's I request the survey json. Then I create a survey layout, in the question region I send a request to get those questions from the questions app. Then do a similar pattern for requesting the answers inside of the questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll need some time to read up on controllers and wrap my mind around coffeescript (which looks great for me who have serious problems adjusting to javascript btw) but I think I get the concept. I think your last edit will get me a long way in the upcoming days, once again thanks.