# Marionette nested composite view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Can I use nested composite view to make the output like this?

```
Nike
  Football, Basketball
Reebok
  Football, Basketball, Running
```

I did write nested composite view in this way. I'm not sure is there any other better way or best practice way to implement this.

Structure:

```
BrandCompositeView
   itemView: Layout1
                #brand<-BrandView (Nike, Reebok)
                #sport<-SportCompositView 
                           itemView: SportView 


BrandCompositeView (generate Nike, Reebok),
itemView of BrandCompositeView is a layout1 with div id are(#brand, #sport)

SportCompositView (generate Football, Basketball, Running)
itemView of SportCompositView is SportView

BrandView and SportView are itemView

Layout1 is Marionette.Layout
```

inside Layout1.js

```
initialize:function(){
  this.brandView = new BrandView({"model": this.model});
  this.sportView = new SportCompositView({"collection":collection});
}

onRender: function () {
   this.brand.show(this.brandView);
   this.sport.show(this.sportView);
}
```

Comment: so you have a collection of brands and each brand has collection of sports activities and you have to render its like a nested list ?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example. I have to do something similar to this. And it is working now but Im not sure is it the properly way to do this.

Comment: checkout this post - its very close to what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232982/backbone-fetch-related-models/25236715#25236715

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Approach I have used for tree structures - [article.](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/)

Answer (score 0):

How about if I want to make this (collection with more than 1 child?)

```
Car: [
    {
    Car1
       name: car1
       image: [{img1}, {img2}, {img3}]
       comment: [{comment1}, {comment2}, {comment3}]
       price: $1000
    },
    {
    Car2
       name: car1
       image: [{img1}, {img2}, {img3}]
       comment: [{comment1}, {comment2}, {comment3}]
       price: $2000
    }
]


<script id="car-template" type="text/template">
  <li><%= name %></li>
  <div id="photo-container"></div>
  <li><%= price %></li>
  <div id="comment-container"></div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just wrote an answer that might help you a couple days ago. Check out this thread - [Construct views for data nested several levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602499/construct-views-for-data-nested-several-levels-deep/25632773?noredirect=1#comment40097317_25632773)

Basically it has you use backbone relational to automatically handle all of your nesting. Then you can just abstract off of that for your composite view inside of your composite view.